# Black screen issue playing videos in YouTube on Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, audio, video, youtube

When I play a video in YouTube there is a black screen.  I can use the interactions and hear the audio, I can't see the video.

I've tried the following:

- There is enough space in my C drive for cache and temp files (40gb free).
- I've opted out of HTML5 playback in YouTube (via http://www.youtube.com/html5).
- I've cleared the cache (didn't work out).
- I've uninstalled and reinstalled Chrome.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the solution!!

** For Windows 7 or 8 - 64 bits. Go to... C:/ Program files (x86) / Google / Chrome /                     Application / 33.0.1750.146 (Is the number of the Google Chrome version you have)

Delete this 2 files:

- ffmpegsumo
- nacl_irt_x86_64.nexe

** For Windows 7 or 8 - 32 bits. Go to... C:/ Program files / Google / Chrome / Application / 33.0.1750.146 (Is the number of the Google Chrome version you have)

Delete this 2 files:

- ffmpegsumo
- nacl_irt_x86_32.nexe

You can watch the video in other browser if you want but is in spanish. Here is the link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8oVfq_0_74s

Comment: I can't believe this, my 3 months problem is finally solved. I wasn't going to do the things the guy in the video you pasted were doing because the person in the video had a different problem. He wasn't able to use the Adobe Flash player even if he opted out of the hmtl player in youtube.com/html, but i am able to as when i right click on a playing video i can see that my player is Adobe Flash player. At the same time, he was able to view the videos without Flash player, but i can't. Anyway, deleting those files fixed my problem, now i can view videos, thank you very much.

Comment: You should spread this all over the internet, because i have been searching the internet for a long time witohut finding relief. Neither forum, nobody gave me a decent solution.

Comment: after doing this chrome crashes when it tries to display a youtube video. great! :/

Comment: Crashes mine too.  Didn't have much faith in the proposed solution, but tried it anyway.

Comment: @Flion: I would almost never follow instructions that start with "Delete these files...", but if I do, I always replace "Delete" by "move to another backup folder just in case something happens". ;-)

Comment: This did not work for me with version 48.0.2564.103

Answer (score 10):

Here is another option for you to try(This worked for me).

Go to `chrome://settings/` click on the `Show advanced settings...` button. Scroll all the way down to `System` section and uncheck the `Use hardware acceleration when available` option. Restart Chrome.

Comment: Thanks Nims. That did the trick for a lot of videos starting black and chunky on Facebook in Chrome.

Comment: This did not work for me with version 48.0.2564.103

Comment: Thanks! Worked for me on newest Chrome 54.0.2840.99 (64bit).