# Clicking a YouTube video crashes Google page

Tags: google-chrome, youtube

I was having an issue with YouTube videos going black, so I Googled around and found this question: [Black screen issue playing videos in youtube on Google Chrome](https://superuser.com/questions/723402/black-screen-issue-playing-videos-in-youtube-on-google-chrome).

Now, however, every time that I click to watch a video, my tab crashes with the ["Aw Snap!" error](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95669?p=e_awsnap&rd=1).

I've tried the recommendations in the Google support page to no avail. How can I fix this?

Comment: Reinstall Chrome and then get `Magic Actions for YouTube`. It's a work around, but it does work.

Comment: I would almost never follow any instructions that start with "Delete these files [...]". I agree with Zacharee1: reinstall, and try to find another solution (i.e.: try to uncheck the `Use hardware acceleration when available` option in Chrome settings).

Comment: And if you ever follow those type of solutions, do not delete the files, just move them away! ;-)

Comment: Yeah, I was stupid enough enough to do this pre-coffee and just deleted. But I followed Zacharee's advice and just did a reinstall.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to determine what is causing Chrome to show the "Aw, Snap" dialogue](https://superuser.com/questions/607563/how-to-determine-what-is-causing-chrome-to-show-the-aw-snap-dialogue)